# Row_Number for most used returning all rows

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have this query

```
select ProductID, ARPVend, count(distinct whsecode) as RN 
    FROM 
        (select pa.product_structure_fk, pid.value as productID, 
             ei.value as ARPVend, ei2.value as whsecode 
        from epacube.PRODUCT_ASSOCIATION pa
            inner join epacube.PRODUCT_IDENTIFICATION pid 
                on pa.PRODUCT_STRUCTURE_FK = pid.PRODUCT_STRUCTURE_FK
            inner join import.IMPORT_RECORD_DATA ird 
                on pid.VALUE = ird.DATA_POSITION20 and ird.JOB_FK = 1514
            inner join epacube.ENTITY_IDENTIFICATION ei 
                on ei.ENTITY_STRUCTURE_FK = pa.ENTITY_STRUCTURE_FK
            inner join epacube.ENTITY_IDENTIFICATION ei2 
                on pa.ORG_ENTITY_STRUCTURE_FK = ei2.ENTITY_STRUCTURE_FK 
        where pa.DATA_NAME_FK = 253501

        UNION

        SELECT distinct pid.Product_structure_fk, 
            data_position20, data_position3, 
            data_position78 
        from Import.IMPORT_RECORD_DATA ird
            inner join epacube.product_identification pid
                on ird.DATA_POSITION20 = pid.VALUE where ird.JOB_FK = 1514
       )a
       group by ProductID, ARPVend
```

that returns this result set (3392 records)

```
ProdID      ARPVend RN
026819143   26815   1
026900102   65187   1
026900102   83551   2
061812104   80705   1
061820327   80705   1
061820327   100538  2
061820578   74868   1
061820578   69124   2
061824934   93617   1
061825815   30392   1
```

From this result set I would like to return the most used vendor for the product

```
ProdID      AROVend RN
026819143   26815   1
026900102   83551   2
061812104   80705   1
061820327   100538  2
061820578   69124   2
061824934   93617   1
061825815   30392   1
```

I have tried to wrap the above query in another query to use Row_Number to rank my Product per Vendor:

```
Select ProductID, ARPVend, 
 Row_Number() over(partition by ProductID Order by rn desc)
from (query above)a
```

This query also returns 3392 records when I would expect there to be less records.
Any suggestions as to what I am doing incorrectly?

Thanks for any help.

leslie

Comment: Does a higher RN indicate more used?  Also, what DBMS are you using?

Comment: Yes a higher RN is the most used vendor.  this is SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is unclear, but if you want to get the second set from first you have metioned in post, use this:

```
SELECT ProductID, ARPVend, RN
FROM
(
  SELECT ProductID, ARPVend, RN, 
          Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY RN DESC) ROWNUM
  FROM firstresultset
) A
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Comment: +1 Essentially, reverse the ORDER BY so that higher counts are on top, and pick the first row in each group.

Comment: @PinnyM, The comment for me or for OP?

Comment: I rewrote the question hopefully that makes it more clear but I believe that I am doing exactly what you suggest.

Comment: @Leslie Suggestion is that you must get only first rows from each partition i.e. `....WHERE ROWNUM = 1`

Comment: So I have to use the Row_nUmber function twice?

Comment: No, look at my answer, you need just add your first query as subquery in place of `firstresultset`.

Comment: My comment was meant to clarify for the OP how this solution works.